# Clipping an image with a custom UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, uikit, core-graphics

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with this problem.

I have a user-created `UIBezierPath` with several points that have come about by user touches.

I can get these to create shapes on a bog-standard UIView by using the `[myPath fill];` function.

What I would ideally like to do is to use the path to create a clipping mask for a UIImage - perhaps as a `UiImageView`?

I tried changing my UIView to a `UIImageView` and then changing the function to `[myPath addClip];` but for some reason it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a graphics context, draw your image, and draw your mask using kCGBlendModeDestinationIn.  Something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0); // size is a CGSize of the result you want
[image drawInRect:imageRect];  // image is the UIImage you want to clip, imageRect is the rect in the context where you want your image
[mask drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0];  // mask is a UIImage containing the mask you drew, rect is the rect in the context where you want your mask - could match imageRect above
UIImage* uiImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. I tried using that method but the 'mask' which im making doesnt seem to be the correct sort; apparently it can't have an alpha component - not even alpha = 1.0.

Comment: Having two views: a UIView and a UIImageView and then using the following code from the view controller did seem to work though:

Comment: CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
 maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
 maskLayer.path = myPath.CGPath;
    [img removeFromSuperview];
    img.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self.view addSubview:img];

Comment: If you have a layer, you can use renderInContext to draw it as the mask.  What happened when you tried the method above with your image with alpha?

Comment: Basically the image underneath doesn't get cropped, it just has a slightly more white/grey bit over the area that is supposed to be 'cropped'

Comment: Actually I wasnt making the image properly. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just one thing: Using kCGBlendModeDestinationIn with a rectangle of solid colour seems to result in a completely empty iamge - any idea why that might be?

Comment: Hm, no.  What solid color are you using?

Comment: Just a single red background. Its ok, ive used layers to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I think that red might be the issue.  I think the closer to black the color is, the less transparent it will be.  Also, I haven't had a chance to play with it yet, but found what should be a simpler way to mask an image.  You can read about it here: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html